# LINQ-to-SQL: Select mulitple properties from top row of each GROUP using LINQ query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I have two tables, Apps and AppGooglePlayMetadatas [AGPM], there are many AGPM to one Apps row. I want to select a set of apps, and for each one, also return some properties from the most recent AGPM row for each. I could do that with this code:

```
Apps
.Select(a => new
{
    a.Name,
    DatePublished = a.AppGooglePlayMetadatas.OrderByDescending(agpm => agpm.DatePublished).Select(agpm => agpm.DatePublished).First(),
    CollectionDate = a.AppGooglePlayMetadatas.OrderByDescending(agpm => agpm.DatePublished).Select(agpm => agpm.CollectionDate).First(),
})
```

But this is ugly, doesn't scale well, and results in (presumably) inefficient SQL with the ordering done twice:

```
SELECT [t0].[Name], (
    SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[DatePublished]
    FROM [AppGooglePlayMetadata] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[AppId] = [t0].[AppId]
    ORDER BY [t1].[DatePublished] DESC
    ) AS [DatePublished], (
    SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[CollectionDate]
    FROM [AppGooglePlayMetadata] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[AppId] = [t0].[AppId]
    ORDER BY [t2].[DatePublished] DESC
    ) AS [CollectionDate]
FROM [Apps] AS [t0]
```

This can be written a little cleaner like this, but still results in the two ORDER BY statements:

```
Apps
.Select(a => new
{
    App = a,
    Latest = a.AppGooglePlayMetadatas.OrderByDescending(agpm => agpm.DatePublished).First()
})
.Select(a => new {
    a.App.Name,
    a.Latest.CollectionDate,
    a.Latest.DatePublished,
})
```

I'm looking for a way to query multiple properties off of the specific row in the joined table in a way that generates an efficient SQL query. If I was going to write this in SQL, I believe I could do it most efficiently like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 a.Name, agpm.CollectionDate, agpm.DatePublished
FROM Apps AS a
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 DatePublished, CollectionDate
    FROM AppGooglePlayMetadata AS agpm
    WHERE a.AppId = agpm.AppId
    ORDER BY DatePublished DESC
) AS agpm
```

Not sure if it's possible to get LINQ to generate SQL this efficient in this situation, but hoping some genius can help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
var result = 
    Apps.Join(
        AppGooglePlayMetadata
            .GroupBy(x => x.AppId)
            .Select(grp => grp
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.DatePublished)
                .First()),
        x => x.AppId,
        x => x.AppId,
        (app, meta) => new { app.AppId, meta.DatePublished, meta.CollectionDate });
```

Does that get you an efficient SQL statement?

Comment: Could it be that you need an index on the DatePublished column?

Comment: Oops, fixing comment: Thanks for the answer! I like the idea here, but it doesn't seem to be returning very fast. Here's the SQL it generated:

Comment: SELECT [t0].[AppId], [t4].[DatePublished] AS [DatePublished2], [t4].[CollectionDate] AS [CollectionDate]
FROM [Apps] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN ((
        SELECT [t1].[AppId]
        FROM [AppGooglePlayMetadata] AS [t1]
        GROUP BY [t1].[AppId]
        ) AS [t2]
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t3].[DatePublished], [t3].[CollectionDate], [t3].[AppId]
        FROM [AppGooglePlayMetadata] AS [t3]
        WHERE [t2].[AppId] = [t3].[AppId]
        ORDER BY [t3].[DatePublished] DESC
        ) AS [t4]) ON [t0].[AppId] = [t4].[AppId]
ORDER BY [t4].[DatePublished] DESC

Answer (score 0):

In entity framework to get "Items with their sub-items", like "Schools with their Students", "Customers with their Orders", "Apps with their AGPMs", it is usually a good idea to use the `virtual ICollection<...>` that is on the one-side of your one-to-many relation. Entity Framework will translate this in the correct GroupJoin.

If you don't want to use `virtual ICollection<...>`, for instance because you think that you can do it more efficient, consider to do the GroupJoin yourself:

```
var result = Apps.GroupJoin(         // GroupJoin Apps
AppGooglePlayMetadatas,              // with AGPMs

app => app.Id,                       // from every App take the primary key
apgm => apgm.AppId,                  // from every Agpm take the foreign key to App

(app, AgpmsOfThisApp) => new         // for every App with its zero or more AGPMs
{                                    // make one new
    AppName = app.Name,
    LatestAgpm = AgpmsOfThisApp.OrderByDescending(agpm => agpm.DatePublished)
        .Select(agpm => new
        {
            CollectionDate = agpm.CollectionDate,
            DatePublished = agpm.DatePublished,
        }}
        .FirstOrDefault(),
})
```

If the App has no AGPMs, there is no LatestAGPM at all, property KatestAGPM value will be null

IMHO the notion of "App with its latest AGPM" is clear and straightforward. Usage will be:

```
textBoxAppName.Text = result.AppName,
testBoxAgpmLastPublished.Text =
   result.LatestAgpm.DatePublished;
```

If you really want to mix the properties of the App and the AGPM, you need to add an extra select:

```
.Select(appWithItsLatestAgpm => new
{
    Name = appWithItsLatestAgpm.Name,
    CollectionDate = appWithItsLatestAgpm?.CollectionDate,
    DatePublished = appWithItsLatestAgpm?.DatePublished,
})
```

I'm not sure it this makes the result clearer for the users of your result. Is DatePublished the publication date of the App?

Usage will be:

```
textBoxAppName.Text = result.AppName,
testBoxAgpmLastPublished.Text = result.DatePublished;
```

Does this justify the extra Select?

Comment: Hi Harold, thanks for the answer! I've never used GroupJoin before, pretty neat! Unfortunately, both suggestions result in problematic code. The first block of code actually runs a SQL statement for each row. If I add the extra .Select at the end, it generates one statement, but unfortunately still has the two ORDER BY clauses, more or less identical to the first block of SQL in my question :/